# Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to generate a pdf report but instead, I'm getting this error:

```
Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type mysqli as an array
```

**MODEL**

```
function pdf($post_id)
 {
 $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_data_utama WHERE nipBaru='$post_id'");
        return $result;
 }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 function getpdf()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_user');
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $post_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $x['data'] = $this->model_user->pdf($post_id);
        $html = $this->load->view('GeneratePdfView', $x, [], true);
        $this->pdf->createPDF($html, 'mypdf', false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add [->result_array()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html) to run your query !!!
From Docs

> The above result() function returns an array of objects. Example:
>   $row->title

```
$x['data'] = $this->model_user->pdf($post_id)->result_array(); <--- here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass simply return array by following

```
function pdf($post_id)
{
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_data_utama WHERE nipBaru='$post_id'");
    return $result->result_array();;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By this `$this->db->query()` you are only executing the query. Not getting the result.
Use one of the various methods to get the result - **result()** , **row_array()** , **result_array()** etc.

In your **Model** -

```
function pdf($post_id)
 {
  $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_data_utama WHERE nipBaru='$post_id'");
  return $result->row_array();
 }
```

In your **View** use values like that -

```
echo $data['nipBaru'];
```

Comment: This is a bad practice when you're going to get more than one row in result, it'll give you one record only

Comment: @MacRathod, I used it because the query will return data for only single post  respective to the passed post_id